# I finished my project, but now It errors: Unknown format name 'string' in <attr name="targetClass">

Tags: android

Some lines's copy....:

```
        eclipse.buildId=
        java.version=1.6.0_18
        java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
        BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=tr_TR
        Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.pulsar.product
        Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.pulsar.product

        This is a continuation of log file D:\Huseyin\PROJECTS\Android\.metadata\.bak_0.log
        Created Time: 2010-10-27 12:15:23.242


        Error
        Wed Oct 27 12:15:24 EEST 2010
        Unknown format name 'string' in <attr name="targetClass">, file 'D:\Huseyin\TOOLS\Android\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4\data\res\values\attrs_manifest.xml'.

        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.editors.layout.gscripts.IAttributeInfo$Format.STRİNG
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.editors.layout.gscripts.IAttributeInfo$Format.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseAttributeTypes(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseAttr(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseDeclaredStyleable(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseResources(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.preload(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.AndroidTargetParser.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk$5.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)


    eclipse.buildId=
    java.version=1.6.0_18
    java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=tr_TR
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.pulsar.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.pulsar.product

    This is a continuation of log file D:\Huseyin\PROJECTS\Android\.metadata\.bak_0.log
    Created Time: 2010-10-27 12:15:23.242


    Error
    Wed Oct 27 12:15:24 EEST 2010
    Unknown format name 'string' in <attr name="data">, file 'D:\Huseyin\TOOLS\Android\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4\data\res\values\attrs_manifest.xml'.

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.editors.layout.gscripts.IAttributeInfo$Format.STRİNG
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.editors.layout.gscripts.IAttributeInfo$Format.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseAttributeTypes(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseAttr(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseDeclaredStyleable(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.preload(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.AndroidTargetParser.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)




    eclipse.buildId=
java.version=1.6.0_18
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=tr_TR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.pulsar.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.pulsar.product

This is a continuation of log file D:\Huseyin\PROJECTS\Android\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2010-10-27 12:15:23.242


Error
Wed Oct 27 12:15:24 EEST 2010
Unknown format name 'integer' in <attr name="updatePeriodMillis">, file 'D:\Huseyin\TOOLS\Android\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4\data\res\values\attrs.xml'.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.editors.layout.gscripts.IAttributeInfo$Format.İNTEGER
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.editors.layout.gscripts.IAttributeInfo$Format.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseAttributeTypes(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseAttr(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseDeclaredStyleable(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.parseResources(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.AttrsXmlParser.preload(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.AndroidTargetParser.run(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk$5.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you have a turkish operating system. I have the same problem. string is sensed as STRİNG in turkish operating system and not STRING! So the difference is İ and I...

Comment: Having the regional settings set to Turkish also causes the same problem despite having English OS. Changing the regional settings to US fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might be casting some variables improperly, or haven't declared them properly.

Could you post snippets of your code?

Comment: there isnt any fault my code... I created a new project and copied my files. The problem was solved. But I cant understand this error...